# I want to change PHP session handler to redis but it doesn't work for some reason

Tags: php, nginx, redis

I am using CentOS 7, Nginx, PHP-FPM 5.6 (through webstatic). All the extensions are loaded. In php.ini, I have written:

```
 session.save_handler = redis
 session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

Now, here is the weird part. When I run `php -r "phpinfo();"` through CLI, it shows that session handler is redis.

However, when I run `phpinfo();` through PHP-FPM (basically through web browser), it shows `files` for both master and local. But the extensions are loaded and supported because `Registered save handlers: files user redis`

Am I doing something wrong? I have changed the values in files that phpinfo reads from (Loaded configuration file: /etc/php.ini; plus, I also checked "Scan this dir for additional .ini files").

I have also restarted the FPM server.

Comment: Look for other ini file for php-fpm

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php “FPM uses php.ini syntax for its configuration file - **php-fpm.conf**, and pool configuration files. ”